# Mongoose update Many documents in DB with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I need some help to update many documents in my products collection, it must match the `updateData.oldCategoryName` and the `updateData.userId`, and then set all the products that match and update the category name with the `updateData.newCategoryName`.

```
let products = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Brasilian', category: 'cofee', userId: 9},
    {id: 2, name: 'Colombian', category: 'cofee', userId: 9},
    {id: 3, name: 'Apple', category: 'fruit', userId: 8},
    {id: 4, name: 'Strawberry', category: 'fruit', userId: 8},
    {id: 5, name: 'Banana', category: 'fruit', userId: 7}
];


let updateData = {
    userId: 8,
    oldCategoryName: 'fruit',
    newCategoryName: 'good fruit'
};
```

How can I set the conditions and update many documents with mongoose? Thanks in advance.

This is the snippet I'm using to update a single product:

```
    Product.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, updateData, {new: true}, (err, productUpdated) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al actualizar'});
        if(!productUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No existe el producto'});
        return res.status(200).send({product: productUpdated});
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mongoose you can use [`updateMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateMany) function.

Try this query:

```
Product.updateMany({
  userId:req.body.userId
  category: req.body.oldCategoryName
},
{
  $set:{
    category: req.body.newCategoryName
  }
})
```

With this query you are telling mongo "Update all elements where `userId` is required userId and  `category` is desired category. Then set all categories that matches with the new value.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Thj7Pe3eaEV)

Comment: Thanks! it's necessary the multi: true option ? it's working fine

Comment: Not using mongoose, with method `updateMany` is not necessary `multi:true`.

Comment: thanks, this answer guide me to search solution for my problem. What about conditionally setting by checking the value of current category? For example conditionally set category to  newCategoryName if the category equals to "foo" category